# Converting pointcloud data in UTM in txt to LAS

Tags: python, utm, las, laspy, liblas

I have text file with point cloud data in UTM format, say

```
sample=[632535.222, 4858488.332, 150.555]
```

I am currently using `laspy`, the parsing from txt is ready, and I plan to generate a new las file using the following code:

```
header = laspy.LasHeader(point_format=0, version="1.3")
outfile = laspy.LasData(header)
outfile.x = utm_east
outfile.y = utm_north
outfile.z = utm_z
outfile.intensity = raw_intensity
las.write(out_path)
```

I am getting the error message:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '632535.331'

which obviously because I am trying to store a float point into 32bit signed int as data format for LAS file.

Is there any way I can get around this with while retaining the precision of the result here? Even with scaling I think it goes beyond the maximum for 32bit int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a scale factor and an offset. I do not know python and laspy but according to [the doc](https://pythonhosted.org/laspy/header.html) it should look like

```py
header.offset = [632000, 4858000, 0]
header.scale = [0.001, 0.001, 0.001]
```

Comment: That looks viable. I will certainly give it a try. I was going to save the offset for the latitude and longitude value.

Comment: It is not "viable". This the way LAS format is designed http://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/LAS_1_4_r15.pdf

Comment: I really appreciate this piece of info. Never used LAS before and really need the basics.

Comment: Added some basic if statements so numbers work out in its data format.